# Strapi : is it possible to track users modifying content?

Tags: strapi

I'm currently doing some research on Strapi in order to build my API on it, and I was wondering if it's possible to expose in the JSON a field that would contain information about the user responsible for the last modification on a particular content ?

I know the API exposes an "updatedAt" field in the JSON object by default that contains the datetime it was last updated, but as I understand it this field is handled by the database when the data is sent to it for persistance ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There is not this feature by default in Strapi.

You have access to the code of your app, so you can add it yourself.

You can create an `History` content type with relation with users and you models.
Then by updating the lifecycle of your entry (afterCreate and beforeUpdate) you create an new `history` by link your entry id and you user id.

Comment: how can i access the *user id* on afterCreate/beforeUpdate ?

Comment: @JavierCastro did you find any way to access any user info on afterCreate/beforeUpdate hook?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020, you can find the person who updated the record, in two places:

```js
// ./api/yourmodelname/models/yourmodelname.js

module.exports = {
  async afterUpdate(modifications, filter, resultData) {
    console.log(modifications.updated_by) // Full user object of editing Strapi user
    console.log(resultData.updated_by)    // User ID of editing Strapi user
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `modules.exports`? or should it be `module.exports`?

Comment: Indeed, fixed, thanks