# Strapi : How to get current user info in models js

Tags: strapi

Following the answer from here : [Strapi : is it possible to track users modifying content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541555/strapi-is-it-possible-to-track-users-modifying-content)

How do I get current user id?

Answer (score 17):

`ctx.state.user` in Controller has authenticated user's data.

Comment: Hi, I'm using graphql and can only override in `service`, any idea how I can retrieve the `ctx` in service? I need to know the user that makes the request too

Comment: This would return `undefined` if your route has no auth policy like `policies: ['admin::isAuthenticatedAdmin']`