# Strapi afterUpdate lifecycle hook not triggered

Tags: strapi

Based off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51541555/strapi-is-it-possible-to-track-users-modifying-content), I have written the following lifecycle function in my in my `api/foo/model/foo.js` file.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async afterUpdate(modifications, filter, resultData) {
    strapi.log.error('here');
    console.log('there');
  }
}
```

However, when I update a Foo in the Strapi admin console, nothing is logged. What am I missing?

Comment: I think thats Strapi 3 way of writing hooks, check out https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/models.html#declarative-and-programmatic-usage....even though I am following current docs, its not trigerring for me.

Comment: Open issue on github: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11828

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Strapi 3, not Strapi 4.

The correct way to write the above code in Strapi 3 is

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async afterUpdate(event) {
      strapi.log.error('here');
      console.log('there');
    }
  }
}
```

And then, of course, you can remove the `console.log` statement because `strapi.log` works just fine.